PDF properties restricting pymupdf from inserting image?
I am using pymupdf to alter a pdf. I can insert text without issue. When I attempt to insert an image it does not show up. No error msgs. On a blank pdf, the png image will show up. The pdf I want to insert the image into was made in Canva if that's relevant. I should say the same results happen using both pymupdf.rect and fitz.rect.
I have tried multiple import versions with success on the blank pdf page. I've tried both filename and streaming as the argument for how to insert the image. Successful again on a blank pdf but not on my stylized pdf. I have inserted text into the pdf and the same page I want the image to try that. I've deleted other images off of the pdf page in case that was causing the issue.
import pymupdf
import os
 
def create_pdf(bar_chart):
    base_pdf_path = "C:\\PATHTO\\base_pdf.pdf"
    base_pdf = pymupdf.open(base_pdf_path)

    #pg.2 bar chart
    fourth_page = base_pdf[3]

    image_rectangle = pymupdf.Rect(50,20,550,320)
    fourth_page.insert_image(image_rectangle, filename=bar_chart)

    output_pdf_path = "C:\\PATHTO\\output_pdf.pdf"
    base_pdf.save(output_pdf_path, garbage=4)
    base_pdf.close()

create_pdf(path_to_bar_chart)


Solved after posting. I used Page.get_bboxlog() to see that the image was getting inserted but below everything else on page. Then I used Page.clean_contents() to flatten the page prior to inserting the image to ensure the image is on top

You did not specify your PyMuPDF version. Issues of this kind should have been resolved by the latest versions. If you still see this happen with the current version, please do submit an issue here providing an example PDF. Thanks. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

Thank you for providing such a great resource. It's the latest version of the module. Happy to add an example pdf if in the link provided.
